# Create private spacemacs layer for yafolding

Tags: package, spacemacs, install

I had tried to create my first (private) layer for spacemacs, for the yafolding package. So I had created the `~/.emacs.d/private/yafolding/packages.el` file with the following contents:

```
(setq yafolding-packages
    '(
      yafolding
      ))

(setq yafolding-excluded-packages '())

(defun yafolding/init-my-package ()
   "Initialize my package"
   (use-package yafolding))
```

And also enabled this layer in `~/.spacemacs`:

```
dotspacemacs-configuration-layers
'(
  ;; ... 
  yafolding
  )
```

Now when I start `emacs` `*Messages*` lists my private layer as loaded:

```
Loading c:/Users/ZsBotykai/AppData/Roaming/.emacs.d/private/yafolding/packages.el (source)...done
```

But as far as I see, `yafolding` did not get installed (`ls ~/.emacs.d/elpa/*yaf*`).

What did I miss?

Disclaimer: as you might noticed it: I'm on Windows, with the official GNU Emacs windows binaries, although I'm having cygwin installed just in case (but without cygwin emacs). Also I had enabled other official layers but they were installed properly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of `(defun yafolding/init-my-package ()` it should have been `(defun yafolding/init-yafolding ()`, as pointed out in by [cpaulik in the official support chat](https://gitter.im/syl20bnr/spacemacs?at=5582ec8adeac73ee5b859fc1).